# MySQL: InnoDB Last Modified

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I want to find the most recent edit date for tables in my database.

This is an example of the query I plan to use:

```
      SELECT `edited` FROM `table1`
UNION SELECT `edited` FROM `table2`
UNION SELECT `edited` FROM `table3`
UNION SELECT `edited` FROM `table4`
ORDER BY `edited` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It works, but I am hoping someone can provide a more performant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may run faster as it will limit each of the selects to one row instead of returning all rows from each table.

```
      SELECT MAX(`edited`) FROM `table1`
UNION SELECT MAX(`edited`) FROM `table2`
UNION SELECT MAX(`edited`) FROM `table3`
UNION SELECT MAX(`edited`) FROM `table4`
ORDER BY `edited` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You use of "may" doesn't inspire confidence! :-)  I was hoping for answers with information backing it up.

Comment: @Sonny,  well considering you trying to get the edited date value from each table, I cannot think of a better way but I would suggest that you may want to consider DB structure modification if this type of query will be needed often.

Comment: What modification would you suggest?

Comment: @Sonny as I do not know the structure or the intent of the data in the domain.  I cannot accurately suggest anything.  But I can say this, if you are planning to need to query your tables in this way perhaps create a main table `(editedTable)` with the edited date for all tables and create a 1 to 1 mapping with `(table1, table2, table3, table4)`  Now your query would not require the union but just a direct query of the `editedTable`

Comment: The data is for a content management system.  One of our clients has asked to put the "last edited" date in the footer.  I think you're going in right direction by suggesting storing a single a single date value somewhere when the records are modified for the tables in question.